# Multiple image upload in Django admin for a gallery

Tags: django, django-admin, inlines

I have spent a lot of time trying different ways to upload multiple images in Django admin but I have failed miserably. I have tried django-multiupload-admin which I didn't manage to make it work and inlines is not what I am looking for. I just want to select several images all at once, upload them under one category and them display them into a mansory gallery. I am willing to pay someone to help me find a simple way. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Admin interface pretty easily using Javascript.
Here is the link ... it will help you design django admin with drag and drop method to upload images

[Django Snippet Article about Image Upload](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1053/)